# Python MySQL connector fails to return all results from SELECT query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, connector, mysql-connector-python

I have this query which I execute using the mysql-connector-python. The code is:

```
try:
    conn = mycon.connect(user=****,password=****,host=****,database=****,autocommit=True)
except mycon.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Authentication error - incorrect username and/or password.")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist.")
    else:
        print(err)
cursor = conn.cursor()
no_of_results = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM name_table\nLIMIT 0, 1000\n")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
while row is not None:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

This returns:

```
(1, 'Mains', 'Mains electrical circuit.')
(2, 'Solar', 'Solar panels.')
(3, 'AirCon', 'Air conditioner.')
(4, 'Oven', 'Oven.')
(5, 'Power1', 'General power circuit 1.')
(6, 'Power2', 'General power circuit 2.')
(7, 'Lights1', 'Lights circuit 1.')
(8, 'Lights2', 'Lights circuit 2.')
None
```

However, if I run the exact same query through MySQL workbench, the results returned are: [image: MySQL Workbench Results]

I have no idea why the two queries are returning different results. I've also looked at the network traffic information using wireshark below, but there's no clear reason to me why this is so.

[MySQL Workbench](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dtKW_lGkOBaWtDWjhtbk9KYTQ/view?usp=sharing)

[Python Connector](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dtKW_lGkOBSlR6MTRSX2hEbjg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the row in prior to fetch the next row like this:

```
while row is not None:
    print(row)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: No that's not it - note that 'None' is printed last. Second of all, if you look at the wireshark logs, you'll find that the data coming back from the server doesn't include the last result.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the rootcause of this issue was? I'm having the opposite issue... the same query in Python returns me one more result than what Workbench does!